# Is there a way to unit-test unobstrusive jQuery scenarios

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing

I would like to test if certain **javascript** (using jQuery or any other framework) applied to a certain **html** code would create certain **behaviour** on a page. For example:

If I have **html** (written in a test as a stub)

```
<div class="order">
  <div class="id">15</div>
  <div class="client">John</div>
</div>
```

And I have a **js** files included (written in a test also):

```
jquery.js
orders.js (the one I want to test)
```

And the main part of the **test** (syntax is imagined)

```
part 1:

  'client'.is 'hidden'

part 2:

  'order'.click
  'client'.should_be visible
```

I want the test to pass only if **orders.js** has this code:

```
$(function(){
  $('.client').hide();
  $('.order').click(function(){
    $(this).children('.client').show();
  });
});
```

I guess, I can do such things with rspec features or cucumber, but is there any more specific frameworks for such tests? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two solutions.

First is jasmine-jquery [HTML fixtures](https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery#html-fixtures). Citation:

> The Fixture module of jasmine-jquery allows you to load HTML content
>   to be used by your tests. The overall workflow is as follows:
>
> In myfixture.html file:
>
> ```
> <div id="my-fixture">some complex content here</div>
> ```
>
> Inside your test:
>
> ```
> loadFixtures('myfixture.html')
> $('#my-fixture').myTestedPlugin()
> expect($('#my-fixture')).to...
> ```

and

> Also, a helper method for creating HTML elements for your tests is
>   provided:
>
> `sandbox([{attributeName: value[, attributeName: value, ...]}])`
>
> It creates an empty DIV element with a default `id="sandbox"`. If a hash of
>   attributes is provided, they will be set for this DIV tag. If a hash
>   of attributes contains id attribute it will override the default
>   value. Custom attributes can also be set.

And also there is [jasmine-fixtures](https://github.com/searls/jasmine-fixture) library. Citation:

> Let's say you want to write a Jasmine spec for some code that needs to
>   select elements from the DOM with jQuery:
>
> ```
> $('#toddler .hidden.toy input[name="toyName"][value="cuddle bunny"]')
> ```
>
> ...
>
> jasmine-fixture's affix method lets you do this instead:
>
> ```
> beforeEach(function(){
>   affix('#toddler .hidden.toy input[name="toyName"][value="cuddle bunny"]')
> });
> ```